# How to fill Pie chart with datas from MySql Datas

Tags: python, matplotlib

I got datas from MySql Database.

```
age_query = "SELECT age FROM test"
mycr.execute(wiek_query)
res = mycr.fetchall()
```

How to fill  pie chart with "res" variable.
Type() shows me

```
print(type(res)) #list
```

When i do

```
x = np.array(res)
plt.pie(x)
plt.show()
```

i got error: ValueError: x must be 1D

What i have to do to fill Pie chart with res variable.

Comment: Please provide `print(x)`.

Comment: @LukaBanfi <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[[44]
 [23]
 [25]
 [39]
 [34]
 [20]
 [44]
 [31]
 [32]
 [42]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.array([[44], [23], [25], [39], [34], [20], [44], [31], [32], [42]], np.int32)

a = a.ravel()

plt.pie(a)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have to use flatten() after pie(x)

```
x = x.flatten()
```